# How can I place html tags according to GWT components

Tags: gwt

I am trying to add a footer in a wed page.
I have added that in a div tag.
But when GWT view is loaded it is now properly displayed.
The GWT view is diplayed over the footer.
Please help.

Comment: Please add some code of what you did, because there are several ways to add footers, and depending on what you did you need a different solution. At this moment it's impossible to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you would do a footer like this ...

in .html

```
<div id='myfooter' style='postion:absolute; height: 50px; bottom: 5px;'></div>
```

in your GWT-module, you could now write into the footer which will then be displayed at the bottom of the page:

e.g.

```
RootPanel.get("myfooter").add(new Label("Hello world!"));
```

But, of course this is just one way of manys ...